# splice() Method does not remove a specific element from My Array

Tags: javascript

I Have This Code:

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

let newMix = mix.map(function (ele, index) {
    if (typeof ele === "number") {
        mix.splice(index, 1)
    }
})

console.log(mix);
```

And The Output Is As Follows:

```
[2, 'l', 'z', 'e', 'r', 'o']
```

My Question Is: Why Didn't `splice()` Delete Element 2

Comment: because you are modifying the array while still looping through it using the original indexes. The map loop will be at index `1` when meeting the number `2` but the array at that point will already be modified and at that position will corrispond the element `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to alter the array during a `map/forEach`, because when you delete an element at index `0,` the element at index `1` becomes index `0`, and the element at index `2` comes to index `1`. So in your case, `1` at index `0` is removed, `2` moves to index `0`, and the next iteration starts at index `1` which has `3` currently. So `3` is removed.

See ECMAScript standard specification for

[Array.prototype.map](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) to get a better idea.

A better way to do this would be using `filter`, here's an approach

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];
let newMix = mix.filter(isNaN);

// OR you can use typeof: let newMix = mix.filter((element) => typeof element !== "number");

console.log(newMix);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you splice, the indices are changing.  I believe the collection operation you want here is `filter` rather than `map`:

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

mix = mix.filter(x => typeof x != "number");

console.log(mix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, when you are splicing the `mix` array the indexes are being modified as a result.

You can use filter instead

```
let newMix = mix.filter(function(elem){ 
 return typeof elem !== "number"
})
console.log(newMix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to `filter` the array

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

let newMix = mix.filter(function (ele, index) {
    return (typeof ele !== "number") 
  
    
})

console.log(newMix);
```